# Upgrading SpringFox Swagger2 to SpringDoc Openapi (swagger3) annotations

Tags: swagger, springfox, springdoc

The [documentation](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) for migrating to SpringDoc from Swagger2/SpringFox does not address how to convert `response` and `responseContainer` fields on `@ApiOperation` to the new `@Operation` annotation. How do I do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576852/9269177) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Before converting to SpringDoc, I was using `response` and `responseContainer` in SpringFox Swagger 2 to explicitly declare, for example, `response="MyResponseDto.class"` and `responseContainer="List"` in order to ensure that all `MyResponseDto`'s properties and containing collection(s) were properly displayed in the Responses section of the documentation for each API call rather than just `"string"` or `"object"`.

SpringDoc handles this all automatically and displays the responses correctly as long as I add the proper typing to the generic for `ResponseEntity` on my REST controller method signature.

So instead of this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/items/{id}")
@Operation(summary = "Get items for component", description = "Retrieves all items for the component by the supplied id")
public ResponseEntity updateMapItem(@PathVariable String id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.getItemsForComponent(id), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Use this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/items/{id}")
@Operation(summary = "Get items for component", description = "Retrieves all items for the component by the supplied id")
public ResponseEntity<List<MyResponseDto>> updateMapItem(@PathVariable String id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.getItemsForComponent(id), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Therefore, `response=""` and `responseContainer=""` are no longer necessary.